# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<package-name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}

Tags: android

I have received numerous Crashlytics reports of an exception my app is throwing, but I have never seen this myself, and I am struggling to understand where it is coming from.

My running theory is that it is related to the Firebase Auth dependency I have - but that dependency isn't actively being used yet. There is a whole sign-up and sign-in flow that my production app has disabled. The only two instances of the library being used in production code is:

```kotlin
// Inside Activity.onCreate()
Firebase.auth.addAuthStateListener {
    val user = it.currentUser

    if (user != null) {
        Firebase.analytics.setUserId(user.uid)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            registerDeviceToken(applicationContext)
        }
    } else {
        Firebase.analytics.setUserId(null)
        Firebase.messaging.deleteToken()
    }
}
```

and:

```kotlin
// Called from Activity.onStart()
fun hasPendingMagicLink(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val emailAddress = getMagicLinkEmailAddress()

    return emailAddress != null 
        && Firebase.auth.currentUser == null 
        && Firebase.auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(intent.data.toString())
}
```

I have included the Crashlytics reports below.

---

**Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException**

*Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.poliziano.notanotherpomodoroapp/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity*

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.poliziano.notanotherpomodoroapp/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

---

**Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException**

*android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity*

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzaz.checkNotNull(zzaz.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onCreate(SignInHubActivity.java:5)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: I have come across this as well. Not often. But enough to be annoying. I have also not figured out the cause yet. I also assumed it was related to Firebase Auth. I removed the dependency completely and moved to just the traditional Google sign-in flow (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android) which uses com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0. The error still exists. Just thought I would add some extra info in case it helps.

Comment: I also had this report showing up in my crashlytics today. Maybe we should file an issue? Could rnfirebase lib the correct place to file this issue report?

Comment: Thrown by Nexus 5 with Android 8.1.0 by any chance? This, and only this device has been throwing this exception right after release for years for me. It appears to be Google's test bot.

Comment: @MVojtkovszky I found the crash issue in Android 8.1.0 Nexus 5X.

Comment: any update about this issue? mine was only from huawei phone, and I don't use firebase authen, I only use firebase for crashlytics only. It's really annoying tho.

Comment: @kinggg I have not seen the issue for a while now so I think whatever the problem was has now been fixed.

Comment: I got some reporter recently... and yes, Android 8.1.0 Nexus 5X too. @MVojtkovszky s theory about google test bot could fit my reports.

Comment: I also faced that issue, but I'm not using firebase auth, so it's for sure not related.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, and it is on a Nexus 5X running Android 8.1.0. :)

Comment: Same issue here, Nexus 5X, Android 8.1.0. I'm afraid there's nothing we can do...

Comment: Same issue here, Nexus 5X, Android 11.